# Is there a config in prettier to keep line breaks?

Tags: javascript, express, prettier

have a problem with prettier extension in VS Code, 
When I write this:

```
const result = await pool
      .request()
      .query('select NumberPlate, ID, TimeStamp from RESULTS order by ID');
```

and save the file, it turns into a single line like this:

```
const result = await pool.request().query('select NumberPlate, ID, TimeStamp from RESULTS order by ID');
```

with the following config in prettier:

```
{
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "prettier.printWidth": 200,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.arrowParens": "always",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on"
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: set printWidth to a smaller value?

Comment: It could be great workaround, but I it would lead into inconvenients in other lines. U thought that it might be a simple thing to solve. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I've always wondered why they call this "prettier". Shouldn't it be called "uglifier" ? It only seems to ugilfy my code.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4131#issuecomment-404603823) and looking at the doc, it doesn't seem to be possible to configure it to keep line breaks.

You could however set a very short `printWidth` or put `// prettier-ignore` comment above your code.

Comment: why have to set a very short printWidth? It's not working. We must use a larger number. I have to put the `// prettier-ignore` comment

Comment: thanks for the answer. But this is really sad. No more prettier then.

Answer (score 45):

Please try adding .prettierrc file to your code and adding a line in the object of the file.

```
"printWidth": 100
```

Reference screenshot:
[image]

Comment: it's not working, 100 is short, how can it keep line breaks?  We must use a larger number??

Comment: @NamLêQuý, this worked for me, but you can surely add more.
You can also refer to the below URL for more info about the property.
URL: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width

Comment: This does not solve the problem it just changes when the problem will happen.

Comment: @Galacticai, This worked for me and did not had any other issues after that and I have used them in almost all of my projects. Can you please elaborate so, I can try to help?

Comment: @RahulMahadik print width is used to determine when to wrap and create new lines. Changing from 200 to 100 means the user will have the same behavior but at 100 columns instead of 200. However, the intended behavior (as far as I understand) is to freely add line breaks without losing them after formatting (similar to Visual Studio with C# formatting where it allows line breaks so you can style your code even with formatting)

Answer (score 20):

Did not find a configuration. As a hack you might want to include a comment on the first line to break:

```
return ternaryExpression //
          ? trueResult
          : falseResult;
```

Comment: wonderful how this hack the process, works for me!

Answer (score 4):

If you open VSC and go into settings then Extentions and click on "prettier" there's a check box ticked under Prettier: 'Require Config'. If that's unchecked it will break your lines automatically
[image]

Comment: (No: you do not need to create some config file, just tick the box.)

Comment: Not sure, but after the above is done, formatting is  not done. Looks like, needs config file.

Comment: Not true. This only stops formatting because lack of config file.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer.