# Prettier - allow line breaks between html elements

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

I'd like to keep some space between some html blocks in my code. However, Prettier wants to remove these lines. Is there a Prettier setting to keep this spacing?

Before prettier:

```html
<template>
  <form>

    <div>First block</div>

    <div>Second block</div>
    
  </form>
</template>
```

After pretter:

```html
<template>
  <form>
    <div>First block</div>

    <div>Second block</div>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: I never used Prettier, but there seems to be a configuration section in their documentation: https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html  
I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to actually do this, you might only use tricks.

### First trick

Ignore completely the file (or file extensions) but you will not benefit from Prettier

### Second trick

Deny Prettier to trim whitespaces

```
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

And add whitespaces in line breaks.
Once again this is not an effective solution, it's only a trick.

An [issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4131) has been closed by devs

> adding and removing line breaks is core to prettier's formatting algorithm

Answer (score 0):

According to @suchipi , Github member:

***adding and removing line breaks is core to prettier's formatting algorithm, so preserving them isn't consistently possible.***

As a work around you can try:

- setting very short `printWidth`
- put `// prettier-ignore` comment above your code.

For Refernce:

- [Github issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4131#issuecomment-404603823)
- [Is there a config in prettier to keep line breaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56975846/13431819)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will work as intended however, in the document for Prettier, there is a section for "Empty Line" that says;

"Prettier collapses multiple blank lines into a single blank line."

By this, you may want to add a double blank line instead of a single blank, where you are wanting a space to be, as it should compress it into a single line rather than removing it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this thread https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4870, it's pretty good explaining why this is still non-existing feature.

There is no simple way for formatter to determine what to keep and what to remove.

So the only practical things you can do

- Add comments to disable formatting in certain places (which is bad idea and never work well, dev gents become annoyed with this super quickly).
- Accept that empty lines would be collapsed (still bad, because of poor readability)
- Disable this feature and maintain empty lines yourself (alternative editor). This one "arguably" seems to me the simplest (best) option in a long-term.