# How to prevent Prettier from braking my lines

Tags: html, visual-studio, vscode-extensions, prettier

I am using VScode Prettier pluging to format my code, im facing a problem where prettier brakes my lines of code.

for example this code

```
<p>{text.replace(/\n/g, " ").split(' ').filter(value => value != "").length} words and {text.trim().length} charaters</p>
```

turns into this

```
  <p>
          {
            text
              .replace(/\n/g, " ")
              .split(" ")
              .filter((value) => value != "").length
          }{" "}
          words and {text.trim().length} charaters
        </p>
```

or this

```
<button className='btn btn-primary my-1 mx-1' onClick={handelUpclick}>Convert to UPPERCASE</button>
```

turns into this

```
<button className='btn btn-primary my-1 mx-1' onClick={handelUpclick}>
Convert to UPPERCASE
</button>
```

my current prettire settings are

```
{
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "strict",
  "insertPragma": false,
  "singleAttributePerLine": false,
  "bracketSameLine": true,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 140,
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "quoteProps": "consistent",
  "requirePragma": false,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "useTabs": false,
  "embeddedLanguageFormatting": "auto",
  "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
}
```

here are my VScode settings

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Popping and Locking Black Theme",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "editor.fontFamily": " 'AnonmicePro Nerd Font', 'Cinecav X Type' , Consolas, 'Courier New', 'Cinecav X Mono', monospace",
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "AnonmicePro Nerd Font Mono",
  "terminal.integrated.fontWeight": "550",
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "prettier.singleAttributePerLine": false,
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "prettier.printWidth": 100,
  "prettier.htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "strict",

  "html.format.wrapLineLength": 100,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": []
  },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "prettier.endOfLine": "lf",
  "prettier.quoteProps": "consistent",
  "prettier.bracketSameLine": true,
  "eslint.format.enable": true,
  "prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true
}
```

how do i prevent prettier from braking my single liners

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current Prettier settings, there are a few options you can adjust to potentially address this:

- jsxBracketSameLine: Set this to true. This will keep the closing bracket on the same line for single-line JSX elements.

```json
    "jsxBracketSameLine": true
```

- singleAttributePerLine: Set this to false. This might help keep
  attributes on a single line for JSX elements.

```json
    "singleAttributePerLine": false
```

printWidth: Reduce this value to something smaller. This determines the maximum line length before Prettier tries to break lines.

```json
    "printWidth": 80
```

Try adjusting these settings and see if it improves the formatting of your single-line elements.

Also, I found this in another [Stackoverflow Section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57242043/19983575).

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have added  "jsxBracketSameLine": true but that dose not fix the issue, i have edited the main post and included my vscode settings

Comment: Are there any other formatting extensions installed aside from prettier?