# How do I configure prettier to not separate my attributes onto new lines and not separate my opening bracket and closing bracket?

Tags: html, formatting, prettier, code-formatting

Before I state any of my problems this is my .prettierrc file so far

```
{
    "semi": true,
    "useTabs": true,
    "tabWidth": 4
}
```

**Problem 1:**
I would like my prettier to not seperate my HTML attributes onto new lines. Examples below.

```
<input
    type="radio"
    name="radiogroup1"
    id="rd2"
/>
```

Should be this

```
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup1" id="rd2" />
```

Another example.

```
<i
    aria-hidden="true"
    class="fa fa-user"
>
```

Should be this

```
<i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-user">
```

**Problem 2:**
I would like my prettier to not seperate my HTML opening angle bracket and closing angle bracket. Examples below.

```
<span
>
```

Should be this

```
<span>
```

Another example.

```
<label for="cb1"
>I agree with terms and conditions</label
>
```

Should be this

```
<label for="cb1">I agree with terms and conditions</label>
```

I tried asking GPT and searching on the internet to no avail. Either I missed some keywords or didnt prompt correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to some other stack overflows you could try to use printWidth to avoid having to long lines of code (that would result in a breaking of the line). I add you a link to that page below:
[Is there a config in prettier to keep line breaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975846/is-there-a-config-in-prettier-to-keep-line-breaks)

You could also try `bracketSameLine`, I post you a link below:
https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#bracket-line
CAVE: This is deprecated as of 4.2.0. Replaced with bracketSameLine